AsyncImage inside Zoomable always filed at first time
I want to load images from the server. Once the images are loaded, I can zoom in and zoom out. The current code is working for some images, but it is not working for most of them end up with an error "BitmapFactory returned a null bitmap. Often this means BitmapFactory could not decode the image data read from the input source (e.g. network, disk, or memory) as it's not encoded as a valid image format."; as per the requirement, there is no fixed image dimension or memory limit. Can any one please help me to solve this?
    @Composable
fun ZoomableImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    uri: Uri,
    contentDescription: String? = null,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
) {
    val imageLoaderStatus = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Box {

        if (imageLoaderStatus.value) {
            Loading(
                modifier
            )
        }
        Zoomable {

            AsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp).height(300.dp),
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(uri)
                    .allowHardware(false)
                    .scale(Scale.FIT)
                    .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
                    .diskCacheKey(uri.toString())
                    .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                    .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                    .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED).build(),

                contentDescription = contentDescription,
                onLoading = {
                    imageLoaderStatus.value = true
                },
                onSuccess = {
                    imageLoaderStatus.value = false
                },
                onError = {
                    imageLoaderStatus.value = false
                },
                contentScale = contentScale
            )
        }
    }
}

